# Best way to update a excel file without replacing it using pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I use to_excel the entire files gets replaced. Is there a better way to do it by updating just one row of the excel sheet without replacing the complete file.

Comment: Yes, use the [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#read-an-existing-workbook) module.

Comment: @Gordon I can manipulate the row/column number from Actual Dataframe and use it to update using openpyxl, Is that what you meant?

Comment: Sorry I think I might have misunderstood your question. If you need to manipulate the values using Pandas, ignore my suggestion.